# Loading state only when data is being fetched

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im trying to show a loader while the data is being fetched only instead of displaying it first thing when landing on the page and when the data is fetched...Any thoughts?

This is what I'm currently doing

```
const handleSearchClick = async () => {
            setItems([]);
            setIsActive(true);

            const { data: { items } } = await fetchData(
                `${process.env.REACT_APP_URL}${page}`,
            );
            items.length && setIsActive(false);
            setPage(1);
            setItems(items);
};


<container>
    <SearchBarContainer>
           <SearchBar
               onClickButton={handleSearchClick}
               onValueChange={handleChange}
               value={value}
               pageNum={page}
            />
    </SearchBarContainer>
    {!isActive ? (/*Display data*/) : 
    (
        <LoaderContainer>
            <RingLoader size={100} />
        </LoaderContainer>
     )}
</container>
```

Comment: What happens when you run this code? Do you get any errors? Are the results what you want?

Comment: no errors. When I run it, the loader is active on the landing page before any data is being fetched or searched for.

Comment: set the default isActive to false if you using react hooks as 
`{isActive, setIsActive} = useState(false);`

Comment: @MurtazaHussain Yeah thats how I have it now, its initially set to false but in the 'handleSearchClick' function Im setting it to true

Comment: set loading state before and after fetching data and try something similar to this in render  `{this.state.isLoading ? <my component or html>: null}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set loading state before and after fetching data.

```js
const App = props => {

 const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
 const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const handleSearchClick = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      const { data: { items: newItems } } = await fetchData(
          `${process.env.REACT_APP_URL}${page}`,
      );
      setItems(newItems);
    } catch(e) {
      console.log('Error', e);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }   
  };


  return (
    <container>
      <SearchBarContainer>
       <SearchBar
           onClickButton={handleSearchClick}
           onValueChange={handleChange}
           value={value}
           pageNum={page}
        />
     </SearchBarContainer>
     {loading ? (
          <LoaderContainer>
              <RingLoader size={100} />
          </LoaderContainer>
       ) : (
        <div>Your data</div>
       );
      }
    </container>
  );

}
```

Comment: setting the loading state before and after fetching data still gives me the same problem, which is the loading state is displayed on initial landing to the page...instead of only when fetching

Comment: You need to share all your component code. I can't understand what's going on there without seeing your code